Laurent expansion of $\frac{1}{(z^5-1)(z-3)}$ with $1<|z|<3$

Laurent expansion of $\frac{1}{(z^5-1)(z-3)}$ with $1<|z|<3$

I'm stuck in the step which is simplify $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{5n}$ into $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ form. The calculate process is
$$\frac{3}{1-z^5}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{3}}=3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{5n}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{z}{3})^n$$
Since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}z^n$, I try to simplify $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{5n}$  then I can use the Cauchy product $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nz^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kb_{n-k})z^n$ to get the answer but I fail.

For $|z|>1$, you can't expand $\frac{1}{1-z^5} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{5n}$. I would write the expansion as following: $\frac{1}{3} < \frac{1}{|z|} < 1$ and $ \frac{1}{3}< \frac{|z|}{3} < 1$, therefore $$ \frac{1}{(z^5-1)(z-3)} = -\frac{1}{3z^5} \left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z^5}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{3}} \right) = \frac{-1}{3z^5}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{-5n}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^m}{3^m}.$$ Thus, the Laurent expansion is $$ \frac{1}{(z^5-1)(z-3)} = -\sum_{n,m=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{m-5(n+1)}}{3^{m+1}}.$$
Edit: The solution can also be written as $$ \frac{1}{(z^5-1)(z-3)} = \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\left(-\sum_{\substack{j\ge 0\\ 5j+k\ge 0}}\frac{1}{3^{5j+k+1}}\right)z^{k-5}$$

You’re right. My expansion is wrong. Could you simplify your result in the $\sum{a_n}z^n$ form?

Yes @KrystalJustin, edited the solution.
